# CSS button works (near) perfect in firefox, crashes and burns in IE and chrome

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have some CSS buttons. The "buttony" effects are done by have fixed size `<span>` elements in an anchor tag, and css rules in the flavor of `a span:active`, `a span:hover` to show button states.
The buttons are for paginating, and so when you are on page 1, the "previous" button is disabled, and when you are on the last page, the "next" button is disabled. this is properly enforced in jQuery. But...

**Issues**

First and foremost, here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9Y2uj/6/

In firefox, everything is great, except that if you click on a button, dont release the mouse, then drag out, the button stays depressed. its not a big deal but its annoying. I think the behavior is documented.

In IE and Chrome, it crashes and burns. My question is **How can I make this work in IE and Chrome?** More specifically, **what CSS properties am I using that are not cross browser compatable?** This is based on the `:active` and `:hover` **(EDIT I forgot also :not)** pseudoselectors which I was not aware had any cross browser compatability issues.

The following is a description of what goes wrong in IE and Chrome. If anything is unclear or not explained well in the following paragraphs, please just view in FF to see the correct behavior, then view in Chrome and IE to see where it screws up.

In chrome, the button just stays depressed throughout page views until it becomes inactive. AND, the "active" "inactive" button logic is completely ignored, for CSS pruposes. For JS, it correctly revents you from using the next button on the last page and previous on the first page, but...For display purposes, I have the JS add a class called `disabled` with opacity settings on it. I have inspected element to verify the class was added, but I see no opacity.

In IE, the `:active` event is never even triggered. Only `:hover` is observed, `:active` is ignored. But, interestingly enough, the "inactive" button rules are properly enforced!

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

the selector

```
a#leftButton:not(.disabled):hover span
```

might not be cross compatible. I'm only guessing however.

Comment: so its the `:not` that isn't compatible? Any suggestion on what I can use instead to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: I didn't think not had any compatability issues either